# Outlines in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I modeled a character and i would like to give it outlines. I know how to do this in blender render, but for some reason it doesn't work for cycles as well. How can I make that effect in a cycles render?

Comment: If you mean Freestyle outlines, this still works in Cycles, you just don't get to see them in a preview render

Comment: Really? let me try rendering it... one sec

Comment: no, i need to see it rendered. i am making an animation but i want the character to be outlined, i want to use cycles if possible

Comment: Please add screenshots of wat you have tried so far. That makes it mouch easyer to come up with good ideas.